# Nil Val fixed rhx

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto, fivem

I am working on a script in FiveM and when the server starts I am getting "attempt to call a nil value (local 'cb')" in the console as an error. See code below that is talking about the nil value is cb(nil).

```
AddEventHandler("f:getPlayer", function(user, cb)
    if(Users)then
        if(Users[user])then
            cb(Users[user])
        else
            cb(nil)
        end
    else
        cb(nil)
    end
end)
```

So I found a post talking about adding "and cb" to the "if(Users)then" so the code looks like this.

```
AddEventHandler("f:getPlayer", function(user, cb)
    if(Users and cb)then
        if(Users[user])then
            cb(Users[user])
        else
            cb(nil)
        end
    else
        cb(nil)
    end
end)
```

But that did not fix the problem.

The results is to get the error to go away.

Comment: Is that event triggered by your code, or by some library/API? What are the event's parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cb is nil then you are still trying to use it like a function regardless of the check for cb being assigned a value. It should be:

```lua
AddEventHandler("f:getPlayer", function(user, cb)
    if not cb then return end
    if(Users)then
        if(Users[user])then
            cb(Users[user])
        else
            cb(nil)
        end
    else
        cb(nil)
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I found a post talking about adding "and cb" to the "if(Users)then" so the code looks like this.

It's right. BUT you call a functional object in your code even if the variable "cb" does not contain it.

Your code should be like this:

```
AddEventHandler("f:getPlayer", function(user, cb)
    if cb then 
        if Users then
            cb(Users[user]) 
        else
            cb(nil)
        end
    end
end)
```

Same with:

```
 AddEventHandler(
    "f:getPlayer", 
    function(user, cb)
        if cb then
            cb(Users and Users[user] or nil)
        end
    end
)
```